# How to Handle the buttons in Grid with event handler attached to Grid

Tags: c++, uwp, c++-cx

I would handle tapped event of some buttons in grid named rootGrid.
But I don't want to attach an event handler to each button.
when the rootGrid contains textblock instead of button, I can access the textblock through the OriginalSource property of TappedRoutedEventArgs.
On the other hand, when contains button the OriginalSource is Grid Type.
However the OriginalSource is not rootGrid.
Why the TappedRoutedEventArgs->OriginalSource is Grid?
there is not any Grid but rootGrid.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and see the [help]. Specifically, read [ask]. You are asking several questions, that are all seemingly unrelated. This tends to make the question *"too broad"* for Stack Overflow as well (see [help/on-topic]).

Comment: I made a demo, but didn't reproduce your problem. Could you please post some codes or share a demo that can reproduce the problem?